# Subquery works as expected, full query effects everything?

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm fairly new to SQL, but this makes no sense to me. Maybe I am not comparing the correct columns, using the wrong operator, or something simple like that, but the subquery runs and returns the correct info as expected. When everything is ran together, it effects all entries with what I put in.

```
SELECT ActiveLocationId 
FROM [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File] 
WHERE ActivePath LIKE 'C:\Videos\Archived\%'
```

Returns 32 entries as expected.

```
UPDATE [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File]
SET ActiveLocationId = 'dc31fbe6-5d2a-4c42-9960-df833fd0e9ee'
WHERE ActiveLocationId IN (SELECT ActiveLocationId 
    FROM [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File] 
    WHERE ActivePath LIKE 'C:\Videos\Archived\%')
GO
```

Effects some 200+ entries, but only those that have the path of C:\Videos\ ... (like Data or Archived) and not those with the path of C:\ProgramData\ ...

It does the same thing if I change it to:

```
UPDATE [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File]
SET ActiveLocationId = REPLACE(ActiveLocationId, 'efc84e2c-800d-45f1-ab80-779d6f812a30', 'dc31fbe6-5d2a-4c42-9960-df833fd0e9ee')
WHERE ActiveLocationId IN (SELECT ActiveLocationId
      FROM [AuroraCore].[dbo].[DeviceEventFile] AS DEF
      JOIN [AuroraCore].[dbo].[DeviceEvent] AS DE
      ON DE.Id = DEF.DeviceEventId 
      JOIN [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File] AS F
      ON DEF.FilePath = F.ActivePath
      WHERE IsArchived = 1)
GO
```

The subquery runs and returns 32 entries, but running the whole thing results in 200+ entries being effected. What really throws me for a loop is that I followed the same design as one of my other queries that works just fine!

```
UPDATE [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File]
SET ActivePath = REPLACE(ActivePath, 'C:\Videos\Data', 'C:\Videos\Archived')
WHERE ActivePath IN (SELECT ActivePath 
    FROM [AuroraCore].[dbo].[DeviceEventFile] AS DEF
    JOIN [AuroraCore].[dbo].[DeviceEvent] AS DE
    ON DE.Id = DEF.DeviceEventId 
    JOIN [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File] AS F
    ON DEF.FilePath = F.ActivePath
    WHERE IsArchived = 1)
GO
```

What am I doing wrong!?

EDIT: The two queries go hand-in-hand with each other so they should only be effecting the same 32 entries. spencer7593 gave me an answer that makes it work just fine, however, I would like to know why having the working subquery in there makes it go haywire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything "wrong" with your `UPDATE`; but it's not clear what you are attempting to do.

The update that's affecting 200+ rows, we don't expect that to match or update exactly 32 rows. Because it's matching on `ActiveLocationId`, not on `ActivePath`.

```
WHERE ActiveLocationId IN (SELECT ActiveLocationId 
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If your intent is to update just the 32 rows that match on `ActivePath`, there's no need for a subquery. Just do this:

```
UPDATE [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File]
   SET ActiveLocationId = 'dc31fbe6-5d2a-4c42-9960-df833fd0e9ee'
 WHERE ActivePath LIKE 'C:\Videos\Archived\%'
```

If there's some reason that you need to have a subquery, but you only want to update rows that have `ActivePath` starting with specific strings, then include that predicate in the UPDATE query, not just the subquery...

```
UPDATE [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File]
   SET ActiveLocationId = 'dc31fbe6-5d2a-4c42-9960-df833fd0e9ee'
 WHERE ActiveLocationId IN 
       ( SELECT ActiveLocationId 
           FROM [AuroraFileServer].[dbo].[File] 
          WHERE ActivePath LIKE 'C:\Videos\Archived\%'
       )
   AND ActivePath LIKE 'C:\Videos\Archived\%'
```

---

Your other query with the similar design, matches `ActivePath`

```
WHERE ActivePath IN (SELECT ActivePath 
      ^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

We note that this will update any row that has a matching `ActivePath`, not just rows that satisfy the predicates in the subquery. The subquery specifies

```
WHERE IsArchived = 1
```

But the outer update doesn't observe that predicate. The outer update will update ALL rows that have a value of `ActivePath` that match a value in the set returned by the subquery, regardless of the value stored in the `IsArchived` column.

Comment: I suppose I need to be more clear. The query that I was having issues with goes hand-in-hand with the one I based it off of. It only needs to effect the same 32 entries that the first query returns.

As it sits, what is going on is that the query is updating all entries that have the same ActiveLocationId as what is returned in the subquery, correct? If that is true, why does the working query only effect the 32 entries I am after?

Comment: You did get what I needed though. Being hand-in-hand with the other queries, it runs just fine, no need for the subquery. Not sure why I didn't see that!

Comment: Your "working" example query has a predicate that matches on **`ActivePath`** returned by the subquery. The query that's updating 200+ rows, that's matching on **`ActiveLocationId`**. You don't have any guarantee that `ActiveLocationId` is unique in your table, there are multiple rows that match.

Comment: Ok, so if I only wanted the 32 entries updated that the subquery returns, putting it where `...ActiveLocationId IN (SELECT ActiveLocationId...` is not the way to do it because it will just update all entries that return the same active location ID as the subquery, correct? If that is the case, why does the "working" query update only those 32 entries? Is it because I have `IsArchived = 1` in the subquery? I appreciate you helping me understand the logic.

Comment: @Trevor: Yes, correct. Only the predicates on the outer query matter, it's going to update *every* row that satisfies the predicates. The difference between the two queries is that they are referencing two **different** columns: one query is using **`Path`**. The other is using **`LocationId`**. Yes, the `IsArchived=1` predicate in the subquery is a difference, **but**... that only affects the values returned by the subquery. The actual UPDATE of the table doesn't care one whit about`IsArchived`. It only cares that **`Path`** on the row matches a value returned by the subquery.

Comment: Looking back at this, now that I have more SQL experience, I can see that I was thinking about how my whole query would work in a completely wrong way. It makes absolute sense now and I know exactly how it should have been written to do what I wanted. Thanks for taking the time to explain it out Spencer! Even if I didn't understand it at the time, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the problem is duplication's. The `activation path` C:\Videos\Archived is having 32 entries. The `Activation Id's` for this activation path also looks to have other records with different `activation Path's` There is one to many relationship between `activation ID` and `activation path`. So if you put the `Activation Path` in `WHERE` condition of outer query in Query1 and query2, you are expected to get same results.